# Datagridview filter by first column not dependent on name

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagrid, rowfilter

What I have

dv2.RowFilter = "[Supplier Name] LIKE '"+FilterByBox.Text+"*'";

So I need something like
dv2.RowFilter = firstColumn + " LIKE '"+FilterByBox.Text+"*'";

but I don't know what the first column would be called or how to grab it and set it as a variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the row, you can call:
`dv2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Value.toString()`.

I hope I understand it correctly.